# Creating a frame that adjusts to the size of the screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frame

I was wondering If there would any way to achieve this frame in a simpler way. I was thinking on a SVG that would somehow adjust to the margin and retain in the process the width of the lines.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Borja-LR/pen/yLZrgVb)

```css
.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}
.frame-topleftcorner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f4e7d7;
}
.frame-toprightcorner {
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f4e7d7;
}
.frame-bottomleftcorner {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f4e7d7;
}
.frame-bottomrightcorner {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f4e7d7;
}
.line-topleft {
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  width: -webkit-calc(43% - 40px);
  height: 2px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
}
.line-topright {
  top: 30px;
  right: 50px;
  width: -webkit-calc(43% - 40px);
  height: 2px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
}
.line-bottom {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  bottom: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
}
.line-right {
  top: 50px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 2px;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
}
.line-left {
  top: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 2px;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="frame-topleftcorner"></div>
  <div class="frame-toprightcorner"></div>
  <div class="frame-bottomleftcorner"></div>
  <div class="frame-bottomrightcorner"></div>
  <div class="line-topright"></div>
  <div class="line-topleft"></div>
  <div class="line-right"></div>
  <div class="line-left"></div>
  <div class="line-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Also, the final goal is a little bit more complex, the corner would actually be connected, as in this JPG.[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnQY8.jpg)

Thank you!

Creating a frame that would be responsive.

Comment: It looks like your codepen example is already responsive? Is your question regarding how to generate curved corners that easily line-up with your box lines? Is that what you're stuck on? In any case, yes, using `SVG` is the way to go. Alternatively you could attempt to render half-circle lines using HTML+CSS tricks, but why? `SVG` much more efficient.

Comment: @Kalnode yes, that is somehow what i managed to do here with very simple code. The problem is that what I really want is to achieve is the border of that div, not the div content as it is now.

https://codepen.io/Borja-LR/pen/gOqyRpN

If I simply add a border, it cuts out the inverted corners.

Comment: Ok; even if you manage to get this border working, don't be shocked a native input field may still look different in another browser/device/OS. I don't know if it's the issue directly here, but it is commonly known that native input elements do not have full styling possibilities due to browser limitations. So most people end up making custom components which mirror the native input functionality (and which keep the native input element hidden within). This gives 100% cross-browser styling control. But it also means you have to manually satisfy accessibility concerns too.

Comment: @Kalnode okey, I guess I'll face that problem If I manage to get it working. But for now, do you know how I can get the red outline in this picture to be seen and the black fill to be hidden? 
https://ibb.co/HrswWtW
Thank you